# How to write a premake5.lua file?

Tags: premake

I am using premake and GNU scientific library in MacOSX to compile a simple example code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>
int
main (void)
{
 double x = 15.0;
 double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
 printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e/n", x, y);
 return 0;
}
```

To compile this test_gsl.c from the terminal I can do

```
clang -Wall -I/usr/local/include -c test_gsl.c
clang -L/usr/local/lib test_gsl.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

I cannot figure out how to write the premake5.lua file.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should start by reviewing [the Premake documentation](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki), particularly the [Your First Script example](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Your-First-Script). If you still need help, show what you've tried so far and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks @starkos . I went thought the examples, made my premake5.lua and it woks. My lua file looks like                                                   
                                                                                                       
    `workspace "mysolution"configurations{"Debug"}
    location("build")
    project "GSL Test"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    files{"./src/example.c"}

    filter "configurations:Debug"
    defines {"_DEBUG"}
    symbols "On"
    libdirs { "libs", "/usr/local/lib" }
    links{"gsl","gslcblas"}
    filter {}`